# Can't check "Allow people to post comments on new articles" option

Tags: comments

Comments are disabled on my client's website. But if I try to check "Allow people to post comments on new articles" option and hit "Save Changes", the page reloads with the option unchecked. I just can't check it.

What is likely to cause this?

EDIT: after deactivating plugins I realized the theme is the culprit, I'm using Karma theme.

Comment: A plugin or theme conflict.  Pull the site down locally so you don't mess with the live site, disable all the plugins and switch to a default theme (2012, 2013, 2014, etc).  Then reactive them one by one to find out which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I ruled out plugins as possible cause after deactivating all of them. The culprit is the theme, I use Karma. I have no idea why it causes this comment option problem.

Comment: Yea, if that's the premium theme for themeforest I don't have access to the code and can't troubleshoot for you unfortunately.  Hopefully their support is responsive.